# POSIX group names: singular or plural?

Tags: linux, permissions, ldap

I'm creating an LDAP structure, part of which, obviously, is group membership.  Things such as `vdi-user`, `vmware-user`, etc.

When creating these groups, is it more proper to use singular or plural for the group name?

Eg. `vdi-user` or `vdi-users`?

Comment: What's the worst that can happen when you choose the "less proper" scheme? Does it really make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Most groups are singular, and dont say user.

Some examples:

wheel, adm, sudo, audio, io, dialout, console.

Comment: I should specify that I added user because there would be multiple group levels.  Eg. `vdi-user` and `vdi-admin`.  What about in this case?  Also the groups are not purely for posix permissions.  They are also for search bases for ldap enabled applications.

Comment: some things may not like minuses in the names, but that's better than spaces.

Comment: Spaces weren't allowed.  It must match `[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z_\-\.]+[A-Za-z0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

At least Linux distributions such as [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups#Groups_without_an_associated_user) and [Slackware](http://ftp.slackware.com/pub/slackware/slackware64-current/source/a/etc/group.new) have a group called `users`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1228560)